# configure azerty keyboard for (light) Raspbian Stretch

Tags: keyboard

How to configure keyboard in azerty in light version as setxkbmap is not known ?
How to make it really persistent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's very simple :

1. log in with `pi` and password `raspberry` maybe `rqspberry` because you are in qwerty
2. type `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`. Key `/` is `!` in my keyboard. You can also help you to write this line with the completion using `tab` key.
3. in this file, change `XKBLAYOUT="gb"` to `XKBLAYOUT="fr"`
4. save file and restart with `sudo reboot`

Not tested, but think it will work with full version also (instead of light).

Thanks to @BowlOfRed for his improvements !

Comment: I have downloaded lastest (Version:September 2017
Release date:2017-09-07
Kernel version:4.9) yesterday and there is "fr" map !  . . . But I think it's not new (nothing found in release note).

Comment: Oups ! Maybe you're right as I have effectively done things with console-data yesterday. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I have found other solutions

**Option A** is like doom accepted answer, but scriptable :

step 2 + 3 can be replace by

```
sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT="gb"/XKBLAYOUT="fr"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

step 4 can be replace by (applying config, no need to reboot)

```
sudo setupcon
```

**Option B** : sudo raspi-config (and follow different menu, that might vary)

**Option C** (same as previous silent mode) :

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_configure_keyboard "fr"
```